# Match <Value> from key-value list (Apigee)

Tags: xml, xpath, apigee

I have the following XML:

```
<Developer>
  <Attributes>
    <Attribute>
      <Name>Role</Name>
      <Value>xxx</Value>
    </Attribute>   
    <Attribute>
      <Name>CreatedAt</Name>
      <Value>xxx</Value>
    </Attribute>
  </Attributes>
</Developer>
```

I would like to match the `<Value>` tag of the `<Attribute>` whose `<Name>` is `Role`

I have tried the following expression (as I read in a SO question about apigee):

```
/Developer/Attributes/Role
```

But it isn't working for me. What is the best approach for this?

Comment: So the value in name & value have to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segments of an XPath between the slashes are the names of elements. You need to traverse to the elements you want to select from, and then use a predicate to select the right one:

```
/Developer/Attributes/Attribute[Name = 'Role']/Value
```